# display image with transparent color at runtime

Tags: android, image, transparency

I try to display a jpg in android-canvas with a specific transparent color. 
It works well with a png and I also know how to convert a jpg to png with java so at the end I have a new png-file on the filesystem.

Now my question:
Is there a way to read a jpg file from the filesystem, set a transparent color at runtime  (convert to png) and display the image at runtime ?

additional comment:
I try to do this in my custom view with the ondraw method and drawbitmap. I can't use an imageview. :-(

regards
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

don't make the image transparent but the view.

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
myImage.setAlpha(value);
```

Value is something between 0 and 255. The lower the number, the more transparent the imageview.

Comment: I try to do this in my custom view with the ondraw method and drawbitmap. I can't use an imageview. :-(

Comment: if you can't use an imageview you have to open the bitmap and change the alphavalue for each pixel. Are you sure you can't just wrap the image byan imageview?